# filename.Contains #(pound) or ' (single quote)

Tags: c#, string, expression

In c# how can I check in the file name  has the "pound sign" and "apostrophe sign" 
This is waht I tried so far but doesn't work. 
I need to send an error if the # or ' are in the filename

return filename.Contains("#\'");

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [IndexOfAny](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50.aspx):

```
if (filename.IndexOfAny(new char[] {'#', '\''}) > -1)
{
    // filename contains # or '
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
Regex.IsMatch(fileName, @"[#']");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
bool HasBadCharacters(string fileName) {
  return fileName.IndexOf('\'') >= 0 || fileName.IndexOf('#') >= 0;
}
```

This code will check the entire file name passed in.  So if you passed in a full path it would check the file name and all of the directory names in the path to the file.  If you just want to check the file name, then make sure to use Path.GetFileName() on the string before passing it into HasBadCharacters.